# How can i set configs to default in counter strike?

Tags: counter-strike

I downloaded a config file for counter strike 1.6 and it changed some settings that i didn't want to change. How can i set them back to default?

Comment: be more specific, what changes ?

Comment: i don't know. there were many commands in that config. isn't there any config to set my settings to default?

Comment: what config file? i just copied a config file to game's folder and typed in the console. exec name.cfg. name:name of that config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete the config file the game would simply create a brand new one (since Steam provides missing files prior to game starting).

If the game is not from Steam, you should try that too or simply reinstall the game if it doesn't works.

Comment: it's not from steam. ok. i have 4 different versions of counter strike 1.6. but i can just play online with one of them and it's settings changed

Comment: Swap the config file from another version with your current working version. The config file works with whatever Counter-Strike 1.6 installation.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Delete your config.cfg file (in cstrike folder).
Then start your CS open console and type "writecfg" without quotes.
and finally your Default cfg will be written.

Source: http://www.nkscslovers.co.in

Comment: Every single answer of yours has a link to that site, and it feels kinda spammy.  We tend to frown on self promotion without disclosure.  If this is your site, you need to disclose that.  I'd also recommend linking directly to the page where this information is, not just a straight generic link to the site.